# Find the extreme points and local extremum if any.

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $ \large \ f(x)= \large \frac{x^4-x^3-8}{x^2-x-6} \ $ .

Find the extreme points and local extremum if any.

calculate $ f''(x) \ $ to find the concavity of $ f $.

**Answer:**

The critical points are obtained by

$ f'(x)=0 \ \ and \ \ x^2-x-6=0 \ $

Now $ f'(x)=0 \  \ implies \\ (4x^3-3x^2) (x^2-x-6)-(x^4-x^3-8)(2x-1)=0$

**Now this becomes complicated to calculate.**

**Is there any other alternative method ?**

Comment: $$\dfrac{2 \left(x^5-2 x^4-11 x^3+9 x^2+8 x-4\right)}{\left(-x^2+x+6\right)^2} = 0$$ Seems like numerical methods are in order to find the five real roots (plot the numerator).

Answer (score 1):

First of all the critical points are obtained only for $f'(x) = 0$. What you need is that the denominator cannot be zero, hence if some $x_0$ (the solution of $f'(x) = 0$ makes zero the denominator, you drop it away.

So you just need to compute the derivative, and use the numerator $ = 0$

The derivative of your function is

$$\frac{2 \left(x^5-2 x^4-11 x^3+9 x^2+8 x-4\right)}{\left(-x^2+x+6\right)^2}$$

And hence you need to see when

$$2 \left(x^5-2 x^4-11 x^3+9 x^2+8 x-4\right) = 0$$

That is

$$\left(x^5-2 x^4-11 x^3+9 x^2+8 x-4\right) = 0$$

That is a quintic equation, not simplifiable.

You need to use numerical methods. For example the most trivial ones is that you may expect (supposition) to have a root near the origin, in this way you may drop the $x^5$ and $x^4$ terms.

Find a solution for

$$-11 x^3+9 x^2+8 x-4 = 0$$

With Cardano Formula.

Or again: drop even the $x^3$ term and solve

$$9 x^2+8 x-4 = $$

Which gives you the solutions

$$x=\frac{2}{9} \left(-\sqrt{13}-2\right)\lor x=\frac{2}{9} \left(\sqrt{13}-2\right)$$

Notice that the second one is numerically $0.356789(...)$.

One of the roots of your initial quintic is $x=0.411079(..)$ so we are not really that far, if you consider the approximations we made.

In any case, for your interest, the numerical roots of your initial quintic are:

$$x=-2.74481\lor x=-0.807191\lor x=0.411079\lor x=1.08202\lor x=4.0589$$

Notice that what matters is that $x \neq -2$ and $x \neq 6$ which are the values that make zero the denominator.